# an issue with my dob sorting script

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am getting the error: line 34: #10#1001: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "#10#1001")

I have just changed

```
[! -f INPUT ] &
```

to

```
[ ! -f INPUT ] &&
```

and now i am getting the error

```
line 34: #10#1001: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "#10#1001")
```

when i run the script.

The script inputs users names, phones numbers and dob and then sorts the infomation and calculates their ages.

What could be causing this error as i cannot work out what operand it is demanding

```
#!/bin/bash

a=0
while [ $a -lt 2 ];
do
    echo Please enter a first name
    read firstName
    echo Please enter last name
    read lastName
    echo Please enter phone number
    read phoneNumber
    echo Please enter date of birth - format dd/mm/yyyy
    read dob
    echo "$firstName,$lastName,$phoneNumber,$dob" >> userBirthdays.csv
    echo If you would like to add another person press 1 or enter 2 to proceed
    read a
done

    INPUT=./userBirthdays.csv
    OLDIFS=$IFS
    IFS=","
    [ ! -f INPUT ] && while read  while read Name Surname Telephone DOB
    do
                    birthMonth=${DOB:0:2}
                    birthDay=#10${DOB:3:2}
                    birthYear=${DOB:6:4}

                    currentDate=`date +%d/%m/%Y`

                    currentMonth=${currenDate:0:2}
                    currentDay=#10${currentDate:3:2}
                    currentYear=${currentDate:6:4}

                    if [[ "$currentMonth" -lt "$birthMonth" ]] || [[ "$currentMonth" -eq "$birthMonth" && "$((#10$currentDay))" -lt "$((#10$birthDay))" ]]
                    then
                            let Age=currentYear-birthYear-1
                    else
                            let Age=currentYear-birthYear
                    fi

            echo "Name : $Name"
            echo "Surname : $Surname"
            echo "Telephone : $Telephone"
            echo "DOB : $DOB"
            echo "Age : $Age"
            echo "##########################################"
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
    echo $DATE

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes on this line:

```
[ ! -f INPUT ] && while read  while read Name Surname Telephone DOB
```

It should be:

```
[ -f ${INPUT} ] && while read Name Surname Telephone DOB
```

I recommend [debugging](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html) your script with:

```
bash -x /path/to/birthdays.bash
```

This will print command traces before executing each command.

Answer (score 1):

`-lt` comparison (and friends) are for integers, not strings. And you turn `currendDay` into a non-integer string by prepending `#10` to it (you do it twice, by the way).

Your intentions here are not very clear. Do you want to compare strings? Then use `<` instead of `-lt`. Do you want `currentDay` to be a number? Then don't prepend `#10` to its value (in both places you do it now).